# how to define not mandatory property in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring 3 with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator.

My properties code looks like as following:

```
@Configuration
public class MyProps {

    @Value("${prop1}")
    public String prop1;

    ...
}
```

If I do not have a prop1 in my .properties file the spring fails to initialize it's context.

The  question is how can I define that this property is not mandatory? some annotation, configuration?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could use a default value:

```
@Value("${prop1:}")
public String prop1;
```

and spring will inject an empty string if the property isn't defined. The syntax is `${property:defaultValue}`.

Comment: you can also set null values: @Value("${prop1:#{null}}")

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if it is possible to make a single property optional but surely you can force the  property placeholder to ignore unresolved properties:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" ... />
```

Comment: In this case all the properties will be not mandatory, But I want only some selected properties be optional, and the rest be mandatory. Can I do this with some annotation?

Comment: you can write separate property-placeholder for that

Answer (score 0):

To ignore all unresolvable properties rather than a specific property, you can use the below bean in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return configurer;
}
```