# Context vs context - setting ignore-unresolvable="true" - PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring, property-files

### Problem

I'm trying to set `ignore-unresolvable="true"`.

I have found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11773267/1688441 from the question [how to define not mandatory property in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773122/how-to-define-not-mandatory-property-in-spring) .

The example they show is:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" ... />
```

However, in the project I have inherited we have a project file called `project.xml` that contains `Resource` definitions with a `Context` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource />
<ResourceLink />
<Resource />
</Context>
```

**Note:** The resources have been removed

When I edit the `Context` tag to add `ignore-resolvable` everything breaks and not even my `DataSource` resource is read. Anyone have any ideas?

I tried the following:

```
<Context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true">
```

### Possibly related:

[spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and context:property-placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542506/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-contextproperty-placeholder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in the specific project a class based configuration was being used instead of XML. I found the following class to which I added `setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false)` in the method that returns `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:appProp.properties"})
@Import({ExternalizeConfiguration.class, AppApplication.class,
        AppPersistenceApplication.class, ConnectBoIntegrationApplication.class})
public class AppWebApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

...Other Code...

/**
     * Bean required for Value annotation
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer test = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        test.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
        return test;
    }

}
```

So my understanding is that annotating this method as `@Bean` causes the method to execute whenever an object of type `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is auto-wired. In this way, we control which instance is used and what params are set on it.